# Configured site for Homestead not working

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Here is Homestead.yaml config :

```
ip: 192.168.9.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: vmware_desktop
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: 'C:\Users\Khalil\RestfulAPI'
        to: /home/vagrant/restfulapi
sites:
    -
        map: restfulapi.dev
        to: /home/vagrant/restfulapi/public
        php: "8.0"
databases:
    - homestead
features:
    -
        mariadb: false
    -
        ohmyzsh: false
    -
        webdriver: false

name: restfulapi
hostname: restfulapi
```

I also added it to the hosts file : `192.168.9.10      restfulapi.dev`

It works when i use `http://restfulapi.local` without mapping it directly as a site since i guess *.local is the default?

Running restfulapi.dev takes forever to load then gives a "connection time out", pinging the IP from my host responds with `TTL expired in transit` 4 times and ends with a

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.9.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

I can normally run `vagrant ssh` and ping 192.168.9.10 and get response, and it's also configured as eth1 on the machine when i run `ip address show`.

Tried provisioning, destroying the VM, setting up everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I attach my Homestead.yaml file for a test project that I am developing using Laravel Framework and PHPStorm.

[Homestead.yaml]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqkHh.png

After making changes to your Homestead.yaml file, execute

1. `vagrant reload --provision`
2. Once the virtual machine has finished booting, ssh into the VM through this command: `vagrant ssh`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the version of php from your Homestead.yaml and run vagrant up and vagrant provision.